# Find all $x$ such that $|4x^2 - 12x - 27|$ is prime

Tags: prime-numbers

Find all integers $x$ such that $|4x^2 - 12x - 27|$ is prime.

---

I first factored $|4x^2 - 12x - 27|$ as $(2x+3)(2x-9),$ but I was unsure where to go from there.

Comment: Well, how could that product be prime?

Comment: $x = - 1$ is an example. You see why?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I should do this beyond bashing it all. Could you elaborate?

Comment: OK see if my answer helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$|4x^2 - 12x - 27| = |(2x+3) \ (2x-9)|$

For it to be a prime number, one of the factors has to be $\pm1$ and absolute value of the other factor has to be the prime number.

So find $x$ when,

$2x+3 = \pm1$ or $2x - 9 = \pm1$ and check the value of the other factor.

There are only $4$ possible values of $x$ to check.